# javascript: push to multi dimensional array (name associated)

Tags: javascript, arrays

i want to create a array:

```
myarray:array [
 "test1" = [
    [0] = 
     {
      name: "mike",
      friend: "tom"
     }
    ]
 ]
 "test2": [
    [0] = 
     {
      name: "mike",
      friend: "tom"
     }
    ],
    [1] = 
     {
      name: "mike",
      friend: "tom"
     }
    ]
 ]
]
```

how i can dynamically add Objects?

In php i would do something like that:

```
$content = {name: "robert", friend: "mike"}
$myarray[$group][] = $content; // Group is the dynamic element
```

in Javascript i try this:

```
myarray[group].push({
 name: "mike", friend: "-"
})
// group is the dynamic element
```

but he failed with *Cannot call method 'push' of undefined* on the first call.

I don't know how many "groups" there are so i cannot init the array with all the group.

Comment: What is the value of `group`? Where you want to push?

Comment: Your array declaration is not valid.

Comment: @Mosho: Oh right thank you - i corrected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use object instead array to hold the information:

Example:

```
function addUser(users, user, group) {
  if (!users[group]) {
     users[group] = [];
  }
  users[group].push(user);
  return users;
}

var users = {};

users = addUser(users, {name: "mike", friend: "-"}, 'test1');
```

Comment: thank you. Is the necessary in javascript to check (L.2-4)? php would automatically set the array if it's not set before